# Spring Boot Problem with Maven build in github actions with postgres password

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, maven, github-actions

I have a spring boot project. I've created a postgres database and run it in docker container with docker compose. I run my project locally and all are ok, tests passed succesfully and maven build is ok. But when I pushed changes to github repo I have problems with CI process.

When github actions run Maven build I get an error like password authentication are failed, but locally I don't have this problem.

I use springboot with flyway and postgres database in docker container.

I will appreciate for any help

Stacktrace in github actions:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
1209
at 
WARN 2373 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

My application-test.properties:

```
# PostgreSQL configurations:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev_sb_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pgpwd4habr
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My application.properties:

```
# PostgreSQL configurations:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://sb-db:5432/sb_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pgpwd4habr
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My docker file

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ENV BOT_NAME=
ENV BOT_TOKEN=
ENV BOT_DB_USERNAME=root
ENV BOT_DB_PASSWORD=pgpwd4habr
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dbot.username=${BOT_NAME}", "-Dbot.token=${BOT_TOKEN}", "-Dspring.datasource.username=${BOT_DB_USERNAME}", "-Dspring.datasource.password=${BOT_DB_PASSWORD}", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

My docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  sb-bot:
    depends_on:
      - sb-db
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      BOT_NAME: ${BOT_NAME}
      BOT_TOKEN: ${BOT_TOKEN}
      BOT_DB_USERNAME: ${BOT_DB_USERNAME}
      BOT_DB_PASSWORD: ${BOT_DB_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
  sb-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${BOT_DB_USERNAME}
        - POSTGRES_DB=sb_db
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BOT_DB_PASSWORD}
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      expose:
        - "5432"
```

My docker-compose-test:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  sb-db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=dev_sb_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpwd4habr
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

My maven.yml:

```
    jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Connect to PostgreSQL
      uses: harmon758/postgresql-action@v1
      with:
        postgresql version: '11'
        postgresql db: 'dev_sb_db'
        postgresql user: 'dev_sb_db_user'
        postgresql password: 'dev_sb_db_password'
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

I checked password and username in all places. So it worked locally, but didn't work with github actions check after pull request. Please help me solve the problem

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question, not in the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Is `dev_sb_db_user` also `root` when you run your workflow?

Comment: @Azeem you are right, problem was in it

Comment: Right. You might want to self-answer this with all the details of why it wasn't working. Thanks!